# Odd PHP Error Message

Tags: php, mysql

When I run some php code I've written, I get the following message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'condition,
>   price, name, email) VALUES('Fake
>   Title', 'Fake Subhead', 'Fake Author'
>   at line 1

I do not see anything wrong with my syntax, however, which is like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (x1, x2, x3) VALUES('$y1', '$y2', '$y3')");
```

Comment: Show the **real** sql query you're trying to perform.

Comment: Thank goodness you provided the real error message, as there's no way to get from your fake query to the right answer! Now you know why it's important not to ask for help fixing fake code instead of real code.

Answer (score 6):

*condition* isn't allowed as a column name (it's a reserved keyword), you need to quote it with backticks (`) to "bypass":

`INSERT INTO table_name (`condition`, price, name, email) VALUES (...)`

Check it out for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: How much more specific can it be? It told you **exactly** what word it stopped parsing at! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply echo out your full SQL query before it is executed and you will find what the problem is. Check the values of your $y1, $y2, $y3 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting that message in phpMyAdmin, my experience has been that it starts displaying your error at the point at which your syntax goes awry. Which in your case seems to be at the word "condition". Which (like @pf.me pointed out) is a reserved word in MySQL.

You'd get the same error, if you changed your column to "select" or "join".

Here's a list of reserved words for MySQL 5.1 (not sure of the version you're using)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the $y's has ' in the string, and it breaks the query. Like $y = "John's example".

Answer (score 0):

its seems that you you need to wrap your column name `('x1', 'x2', 'x3')`